Why I am getting this error: exited with code=3221225725
//holds the previous node value for checking the BST
int previous = INT_MIN;    
//This function simply checks that whether the given binary tree is a BST or not.
bool isBST(Node *root){
    if(root==NULL){
        return true;
    }
    if(isBST(root->left)==false){    //check for roots left subtree
        return false;
    }
    if(root->key <= previous){      //setting the root key value as previous
        return false;
    }
    previous=root->key;             //checking for right subtree
    return (isBST(root->right));
}

int main(){
    Node *root = new Node(4);  
    root->left = new Node(2);  
    root->right = new Node(5);  
    root->left->left = new Node(1);  
    root->left->right = new Node(3);  
      
    if(isBST(root))  
        cout<<"Is BST";  
    else
        cout<<"Not a BST";  
          
    return 0;
}

**Why I am getting this error: exited with code=3221225725 in VS Code **

Code 3221225725
Error can indicate a bug in the executed software that causes stack overflow, leading to abnormal termination of the software.

If you see, 3221225725 is hex 0xc00000fd and that is stack overflow error.
In your code isBST calling itself recursively. Recursive functions are prone to stack overflow error. Pass additional parameter (default value INT_MIN) when you call isBST. Being lowest value as default, you will able to check this parameter is called recursively or by main function. Thus avoiding calling in recursion infinitely.
bool isBST(Node *root, int previous = INT_MIN) 
{
    if (root == NULL) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (!isBST(root->left, previous)) 
    { // check for left subtree
        return false;
    }

    if (root->key <= previous) 
    { // check current node with previous
        return false;
    }

    return isBST(root->right, root->key); // update previous for right subtree
}

